# Error of not enough arguments while using quad in matlab

Tags: matlab, quad

I used the quad function this way:

```
F = @(x)1./(x.^3-2*x-5);
Q = quad(F,0,2);
```

but now my F function was changed to:

```
F = @(x,y) y./(x.^3-2*x-5);
```

I am using Quad inside some other loop so I've got y value for each iteration.

I tried to use Quad that way:

```
Q = quad(F(y),0,2);
```

but i get an error of not enough arguments. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function defined only in `x` to evaluate `F(x,y)` when `y` is known

```
Q = quad(@(x) F(x,y), 0, 2)
```